# Using pandas.Series.str.get: what is the correct way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas

I am following Wes Mckinney's wonderful book to get up to speed with `pandas`. I however can't seem to get why `pandas.Series.str.get` won't work. I've looked at a few Github issues and questions on here but none seems to help.

**Data**

```
data = pd.Series({'Dave': 'dave@google.com', 'Steve': 'steve@gmail.com', 'Rob': 'rob@yahoo.com', 'Wes': np.nan}
)
```

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np
pattern = '[a-zA-Z0-9]+@.*'
matches = data.str.match(pattern)
matches.str.get(1)
```

The above code should work and result in something like:

```
Dave NaN
Rob  NaN
Steve NaN
```

I did use a different regex pattern than used in the book but don't think that's the issue.

**ERROR**:

> raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string " "values!")
>   AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values

What am I missing? I am using pycharm community and python 3.6.6,
pandas Version: 0.24.2
if that makes a difference.

Here's a screenshot from the book:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @EdChum, I could use that. It's just puzzling to me why the author used the same code to achieve the desired results while I can't. I've seen an issue that was apparently fixed in 2018 that references `str.get`. Being new to pandas and python in general, I did not go into much detail of the issue since I would probably not follow. It's [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/20667)/.

Comment: Calling `str.get` only makes sense when the dtype iterable, if you look at the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html#pandas.Series.str.get) they show all the different behaviours but it doesn't make sense here when it's a boolean mask

Comment: Alright, thanks. I guess I'll just forget about it and move on to something else for now. I'll leave this here in case someone ever gets puzzled by the same. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get a series containing `NaN`s is because `matches` is a boolean `Series`:

```
In[58]:
matches

Out[58]: 
Dave     True
Steve    True
Rob      True
Wes       NaN
dtype: object
```

So it doesn't make sense to return an element at the ordinal position in this case, hence why you get a `Series` of `NaN`s.

If you look at the example in the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html#pandas.Series.str.get

```
In[61]:
s = pd.Series(["String",
...               (1, 2, 3),
...               ["a", "b", "c"],
...               123,
...               -456,
...               {1: "Hello", "2": "World"}])
s

Out[61]: 
0                        String
1                     (1, 2, 3)
2                     [a, b, c]
3                           123
4                          -456
5    {1: 'Hello', '2': 'World'}
dtype: object

In[62]:
s.str.get(1)

Out[62]: 
0        t
1        2
2        b
3      NaN
4      NaN
5    Hello
dtype: object
```

So here it's returning the element at the ordinal position for each row, You can see that for some rows there is no 2nd element so it returns `NaN`.